# Select values from 2 tables matching with junction table

Tags: sql

I need to select values from table A and table B using the junction table. The result set should have values from both the tables.
Example:

```
Table A 
ID
1
2
3
4
5

Table B
ID
8
9
Junction Table
ID1    ID2
1      8 
6      9
```

The result should like below if the value from TABLE A or B exists in junction then it should get either of 1 value from junction table
Result for the above example should be

```
ID
1
2
3
4
5
9
```

Comment: I'm sorry, could you explain it a little better? You have 3 tables total (A, B and a third with two sets of ID)? The result set should have rows from A and B if they are present in that third table?

Comment: Please add more detail about what data is not in the table. It looks like you want all IDs from tableA or tableB, *except* tableB's ID when both IDs from the junction table are in tableA and tableB, but it's not clear.

Comment: Table A  Table B  Junction Table 
1             8                1 8
2             9                6 9
3     
4     
5     
     
Result     
1     
2     
3     
4     
5     
9

Answer (score 0):

I don't follow the description of the logic.  But, based on the data, it appears to be all ids in `A` along with ids from `B` that are paired with an id from `A` in `junction`.

If so:

```
select a.id
from a
union all
select b.id
from b
where not exists (select 1
                  from junction j join
                       a
                       on j.id1 = a.id
                  where j.id2 = b.id
                 );
```

This is based on the data, so it is only looking at `id2` for the match to `b.id`.

Comment: Thanks Gordon the below query worked.select a.id
from a
union all
select b.id
from b
where not exists (select 1
              from junction j join
                   a
                   on j.id1 = a.id
              where j.id2 = b.id
             );

Comment: @Neta . . . I see.  You want `9`, not `8` -- the one that *doesn't* match.